# xlrd reading cell with text when empty

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I don't understand why xlrd is reading a cell with value u'' as containing some text. All throughout the column it reads empty cells as having text although a couple of times it recognises as them not having it.

If anyone has ever encountered this same problem it would help!

Thanks

Comment: Please, put some code or an example. We may help you more easily.

Comment: You said that a couple of times, xlrd recognizes empty cells as being empty. What do you mean by that? It's normal for "empty" cells to have a value that is a string of length zero.

Answer (score 0):

for example: the value of u'asdf' is the same as just 'asdf'
the u'' means, that the value type is of unicode

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html (see at "The Unicode Type")

Does an error occur on your code, or did you just whitness this and could not find an explanation for it?